# не обрабатывается столкновение

Tags: python, pygame, обработка-столкновений

квадрат входит в другой квадрат игнорируя что он существует. входить не должен.

```
import pygame as pg
import random
sc = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 660))
obj = [[0, 0], [20, 0]]
fps = 10
ck = pg.time.Clock()
i = 0
i2 = 0
i3 = 0
run = True
while run:
    ck.tick(fps)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    sc.fill((0, 0, 0))
    i2 = 0
    while i2 <= len(obj)-1:
        i = random.randint(-1, 1)*20
        i3 = random.randint(-1, 1)*20
        obj[i2][0] += i
        obj[i2][1] += i3
        if obj.count(obj[i2]) > 1:
            obj[i2][0] -= i
            obj[i2][1] -= i3
        if obj[i2][0] < 0:
            obj[i2][0] = 0
        if obj[i2][0] > 20:
            obj[i2][0] = 20
        if obj[i2][1] < 0:
            obj[i2][1] = 0
        if obj[i2][1] > 0:
            obj[i2][1] = 0
        pg.draw.rect(sc, (254, 254, 254), (obj[i2][0], obj[i2][1], 20, 20))
        i2 += 1
    pg.display.update()
pg.quit()
```

Comment: Опишите ваш вопрос подробнее и назовите переменные понятно. Очень сложно понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать.
Сходу я не могу понять, где тут второй квадрат и что должно мешать им пересекаться.

Comment: можно запустить код на своем компьютере. переменная i2 нужна что бы цикл повторялся столько раз сколько объектов в списке obj. i и i3 нужны чтобы квадраты двигались. i изменения по x, а i3 изменения по y. квадраты не должны быть на одних координатах просто потому.